# How to migrate strong entities/tables first into the database in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, database-migration

I am working with database migrations in Yii2.

I have a problem while migrating all the migrations into the database by running command i.e. yii migrate

The problem is that Yii try to creates the table first which has a foreign key of another table which is not created yet but already in the migration sequence. So the got the following error

- *cannot create foreign key constraint*

Example:

Table 1: Users (id, role_id, name, email) // role_id is the foreign key here

Table 2: Roles (id, title, status)

So how can I tell Yii that first migrate Roles table and then migrate Users table into the database. I have over 50 tables like that.

Thanks :)

Comment: Migrations are run in the order of their timestamps, maybe just change it in file and class name.

Comment: Yes this is a solution but I have to change in over 50 files.

Comment: Other method is to run specified migration by name in the order you like (one by one) so I think it's better to change names one time.

Comment: Thanks @Bizley for help :)